# JQuery - Get Value Using a Selector

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to select the first link on a page after the page has completely loaded and redirect the page to the link on the first page.

I understand how to use a selector, but I'm stumped as to how I can pick up the first item after the page loads. I'm assuming once I have the value I could use

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
```

To then take the user to proper page once I have the dynamic link's value.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   window.location = jQuery("a[href]:first").attr("href");
});
```

A selector with the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) pseudo-class selects the first matched element. For more information on selectors, check out [jQuery's excellent documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

**EDIT**

Actually ran my code and noticed that it was returning an empty string. This was because it was picking up the first `a` tag which happened to *not* have an `href` attribute. I've changed the selector to only select `a` tags with an `href` attribute.

Comment: I wonder if it wouldn't be better to use the chained method `.attr('href')` in this case, just because he's learning jQuery. I realize that the href attribute is going to be there since it's a link, but he could also use the same concept on another element if the attr is there. (mostly a for @Ryan comment, not so much @Vivn Paliath, but a good comment for commentary)

Comment: @drachenstern - I think you caught me in the middle of an edit - I changed it to `attr("href")` for the exact same reason that you provided :)

Comment: Wont' work if there's an element that looks like <a href="#bookmark">

Answer (score 3):

For your selector, use a:first. This will give you the first anchor tag on the page. You can then set the location to the href attribute of the anchor tag.

Something like:

```
location = $("a:first").attr("href");
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll point out that redirects are easily defeated.  Don't rely on this for anything "secure."

You may also find that you need the first anchor that actually has an href:

```
$("a[href]:first").attr("href");
```

Comment: There's no need to specify the 0-th element and in fact, that might cause problems if your wrapped set contains no elements?  I would rewrite that as $("a[href]:first").attr("href");

Answer (score 1):

Are you using this syntax by chance in a script tag in your page?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Your code here
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('href').indexOf('http')==0) {
      window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    }
  });
});
```

This code will work because:
It makes sure the page doesn't take a static anchor tag () and mistake it for a link. It will only use that link if it starts with an http: and if not, it goes over to the next occurrence of the  tag.

Comment: hehe.. and I also had the wrong brackets. Updated! And your addendum below about the document ready function is perfect. Shouldn't forget that...

Comment: FYI The above methods that pick out the 'a[href]' won't work because some links have '#' in them for whatever reason.